# Mouse button modifiers - Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to set up my mouse buttons to perform different functions if I press and hold them, or if I press them while holding down <kbd>shift</kbd>/<kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

As some trivial examples:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-leftMouseButton = "back" in firefox history?
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>-rightMouseButton = go forward in firefox,
- Press-and-hold right mouse button = some other action in firefox (eg, move to opposite screen and maximize).

EDIT:

I forgot to mention I have 5 mouse buttons. (Microsoft Wireless Laser Mouse 6000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can map those combinations to other key combinations, as below.

<kbd>shift</kbd> + left mouse -> <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>

```
+LBUTTON::SendInput,!{LEFT}
```

<kbd>shift</kbd> + right mouse -> <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd>

```
+RBUTTON::SendInput,!{RIGHT}
```

Beyond that, you can execute a series of commands, if you wanted to also, say, activate a Firefox window first.

To do the press-and-hold, you'd have to use a timer and it is a bit more complicated. You'd also need to figure out how you want to execute "some other action." Do you have a set of keystrokes that would achieve what you say? For example, I have <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> mapped to switch screens, so I'd send that and then Windows key + up to do it.